# Should i setup the subdomain in godaddy or hostinger? domain is pointed from godaddy to hostinger

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I have a domain bought from godaddy and it is currently pointed at hostinger. I need to setup a subdomain (api.myapp.com) will point this subdomain as my hostname to AWS. Im not sure if where should i set the subdomain. Is it in godaddy or hostinger?

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the api.myapp.com subdomain in godaddy and point it to your AWS.

Answer (score 0):

As [juanshotman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13530235/juanshotman) said, point your subdomain to the server that you have set up in AWS.